# 30 y.o. air pump troubleshooting. Where do I start?

Tags: hvac, ducts, heat-pump, troubleshooting

500 sq.ft. apartment, 2nd floor, 32 y.o. through the wall, **ducted** air heat pump. The pump is installed in a closet next to the apartment (separate entry), and the air ducts spread from there along the front of the condo unit to 5 openings. It heats well, cools not so well: when the inside of the apartment heats to 79 during the day, it can bring it down to about 70; but the outside temperature is about 70 as well, so just a window fan would have helped as much.

I found that:

1. Some of the ducts have leaks
2. Air leaks out of the unit
3. Some of the duct insulation is off, exposing ducts to the temperature in the HVAC closet.
4. Coils seem to be relatively cold to touch after 15 mins of operation

R12 is used as a refrigerant.

I appreciate starting points as to how to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Chances are you've lost some refrigerant due to a leak. You're getting partial cooling. A fan wouldn't reduce the interior temperature to the exterior temperature due to solar gain.

Comment: I am able to get access to pipes inside the unit. Visual inspection of the refrigerant pipes is the first step. To my knowledge, the system have not been topped of with R12 since installation, so I will be looking for a very small leak. More data to follow

Comment: You need to have this unit serviced by a competent  A/C company to get it  working properly. If it really R12, that refrigerant is really expensive.